# pushState() back-button and page refresh

Tags: javascript, back-button, page-refresh, html5-history

First off, I'm **totally** aware that you can't disable the browser's back-button.

I have single-page chat application which is initially loaded from a django apps 'index' view.  messages are sent/received via a different endpoint.  I simply want to make it so that if the user were to click on the back-button (or equivalent actions), that they won't reload the page from the server, thus destroying the chat session (the chat messages themselves are ephemeral).

I was *thinking* of doing a pushState({'state': 'some-uuid-or-something'}, 'same title') every so often, hoping this would add additional items to the session history, meaning the user would have to *intentionally* go way back in their history to actually hit the server again.  Would this work?  Since I'm trying to achieve a no-op, do I need to even register a popState handler?

Also, if the current state (same url as served by django) is different than the state when the page was initially loaded, will a page refresh simply refresh the current state (a no-op) or would it hit my server and thus discard my ephemeral chat messages?

Any clarifications/help appreciated in advance

Comment: on page load use history.replaceState, on popstate event use history.pushState

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell ok. I think i understand. i figure this solves the back-button issue, but does it solve the refresh-page issue as well?

Comment: page shouldn't refresh if history state is saved programatically

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell ok. i'll give this a shot.  hopefully this will turn out to be the answer to my question